# Reading Excel files on Python - file untraceable

Tags: python, excel, import

Here is my problem:

I have an assignement for uni where we're asked to make an analysis of some problem (not important). 
We're given datas on excel files, and we are supposed to use python to code and solve our problem. 
I've been through the internet to find out I had to install pip and to install the xlrd and openpyxl libraries (I wasn't sure which one).
I am hoping to be able to eventually use these files through Python and to manipulate the datas just thanks to some simple line commands, and I guess now I've fixed everything except one thing.

On Python Shell, I'm writting the following instructions:

```
import xlrd

import openpyxl

file_location = C:/Audrey/Desktop/CW/time.xlsx"

workbook = xlrd.open_workbook(file_location)
```

And then I got the line

> "No such file or directory".

Though, I am sure, that I did not any mistake.
I have absolutely no clue what to do. 
Did I forget a step ?
Can someone help ?

Comment: Use openpyxl, xlrd is for .xls files. See this link: http://www.python-excel.org/

Comment: @trans1st0r: Actually, xlrd has been able to read .xlsx since version 0.8.0, which was released in August 2012.

Answer (score 0):

Forgot a quotation mark I believe:

`file_location = "C:/Audrey/Desktop/CW/time.xlsx"`